# Removing NaN value from legend in matplotlib map plotted from GeoPandas DataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas, legend, mapping, matplotlib

I have a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame which I want to plot against a specific column.

```
for day in days_list:
    df2 = csv_file[["state_id", "state_name", "tmx_corrl"]].loc[csv_file["days"] == day] 
    new_df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'state_id', how="left")
    new_df.drop(columns=['state_name_y'], inplace = True)
    new_df.rename(columns={"state_name_x": "state_name"}, inplace = True)


    #new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="state_id", how="left")
    #df_new = new_df.dropna(axis="index", how="any")
    df_new = new_df.fillna(0)
    #df_new = new_df.replace(np.nan,0)
    

    cmap = ListedColormap(["red", "orange", "blue", "green"])


    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
    df_new.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, color='black')
    

    df_new.plot(
    ax=ax,
    column=new_df["tmx_corrl"],
    linewidth=1,
    cmap=cmap,
    scheme='User_Defined',
    edgecolor='black',
    alpha=0.9,
    classification_kwds={'bins':[0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1]},
    legend=True
    )
    
    ax.set_title("Day "+ str(day)+" Rainfall")
    
    
    plt.tight_layout()

    plt.savefig("day_{}.png".format(day), dpi=300)
```

This column have some `NaN` values, like at column no 7 in this dataframe
[image: 7 Dadara & Nagar Havelli 26 POLYGON ((73.20657 20.12216, 73.20797 20.10650... NaN]

which I am removing using several methods

1. Dropping the column with NaN value

```
    df_new = new_df.dropna(axis="index", how="any")
```

2. Filling the NaN value to Zero

```
    df_new = new_df.fillna(0)
```

3. Replacing the NaN value to Zero

```
    df_new = new_df.replace(np.nan,0)
```

`NaN` value changed to zero
[image: 7 Dadara & Nagar Havelli 26 POLYGON ((73.20657 20.12216, 73.20797 20.10650... 0.0]

But it is still shows the `NaN` value in the map legend which I want to remove i.e. the interval " **nan - 0.00** " in the legend, as it is altering the whole order of color coding.

[image: wrong colour]

Can somebody suggest, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change `column` parameter from `new_df["tmx_corrl"]` to `df_new["tmx_corrl"]` in `plot` method.

```
df_new.plot(
    ax=ax,
    column=df_new["tmx_corrl"], ## change here
    ...
    ...
    )
```