# Legend colour not matching as assigned in the bins in matplotlib map plotted from GeoPandas DataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas, legend, mapping, matplotlib

I have a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame which I am plotting against a specific column and the colour of the output/map is not matching with the colour assigned to different bins/intervals. It should ideally be unique for distinct intervals but the legends are taking same colour for different intervals

```
##colour

    cmap = ListedColormap(["red", "orange", "blue", "green"])

## bins/intervals

    classification_kwds={'bins':[0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00]}
```

Same colour legend for 2 different intervals is coming in the output. Why it is happening so?

[image: Same colour legend]

The code is as follows

```
for day in days_list:
    attribute = "far" 
    df2 = csv_file[["state_id", "state_name", attribute]].loc[csv_file["days"] == day] 
    new_df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'state_id', how="left")
    new_df.drop(columns=['state_name_y'], inplace = True)
    new_df.rename(columns={"state_name_x": "state_name"}, inplace = True)
    df_new = new_df.fillna(0)
    
    cmap = ListedColormap(["red", "orange", "blue", "green"])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
 
    df_new.plot(
        ax=ax,
        column=attribute,
        linewidth=1,
        cmap=cmap,
        scheme='User_Defined',
        edgecolor='black',
        alpha=0.9,
        classification_kwds={'bins':[0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00]},
        legend=True
    )
    
    ax.set_title("Day "+ str(day)+ " " + str(attribute))
    
    plt.tight_layout()

    plt.savefig("day_{}.png".format(day), dpi=300)
```

This is the Geopandas GeoDataFrame

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change `column` parameter from `df_new[attribute]` to `attribute` in `plot` method.

```
df_new.plot(
    ax=ax,
    column=attribute, ## change here
    ...
    ...
    )
```

If it doesn't work, you may be using the wrong column name or wrong `bins` values. Check the range of `"far"` column. In your [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/382633/29431) you use another column name and the same `bins` values for the same script, but styling looks like correct.

Comment: I have tried as suggested, but it didn't worked, The column name is correct though. I have attached the table, I Can share the dataset, if you wanna to have a look. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: The range of “far” is between 0 and 1 (please see the range from the table), and the bins value are within this range only. In this script, I have just assigned the new variable “attribute”, so that i don’t have to change the column name everywhere in the script. But it’s now working.

Comment: If you found where the problem was and what the solution was, please add your solution as an answer so that future users who have the same problem may benefits from the solution.

Comment: Hi @Kadir, I saw the dataframe precisely again. Actually, there were no values between the 4th interval (0.75 - 1.00), that's why it was assigning same colour to both the intervals (0.50 - 0.75 and 0.75 - 1.00). But I want to keep the user assigned bins static i.e don't want to change the intervals assigned. Is there any way that to proceed, like if the value in specific range is not available, then matplotlib skip that interval while plotting inside the polygons, and still shows that range in the legend?